# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'o' of null" | Google Print Android

Tags: android

I am implementing Google Print from my Android App. And i have implemented but when i do the print i am getting this error -

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(287)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'o' of null", source: https://www.google.com/cloudprint/client/1572946473-dialog_mobile.js (287)
```

I have search about this error. And i got
`settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);`

But still i am getting same error.
Please help me out.

Thanks in Advance.

Code to Call PrintDialog.

```
if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
    Toast.makeText(FinalCanvasScreen.this,
            "Network connection not available, Please try later",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/xyz.pdf");
    Intent printIntent = new Intent(FinalCanvasScreen.this, PrintDialogActivity.class);
    printIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
    printIntent.putExtra("meCard", "meCard print ");
    startActivity(printIntent);
}
```

Comment: You know if It's posible use an URL to print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed this issue by adding:

```
@android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
```

on all methods of the Javascript Interface class.

Comment: where should I put that?